# Maneiras simples de se quebrar um *while* com uma função

Tags: python, funções, while, break

Geralmente me deparo com esse problema:

```
while True:

  input_chute = int(input("chute: "))

  if input_chute == 0: break

bla bla bla ...
```

Nesse exemplo acima eu quebro o while com uma condição e um `break`, porém, quando eu crio uma função:

```
def jogo():
  input_chute = int(input("chute: "))

  if input_chute == 0: break

while True:

  jogo()

bla bla bla ...
```

acabo precisando usar *global* e uma variável só para funcionar como contador ou tenho que deixar `if input_chute == 0: break` fora da função.

Existe alguma forma mais fácil (ou só diferente) de se fazer isso?

obs: ainda sou junior, não conheço muita coisa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não parece ser uma boa ideia. Parece que o `while` faz parte do algoritmo da função (ele é um que pede um dado o validando) e não deveria ser separado. Inclusive o nome da função não é boa e por isso já indica que tem algo errado ali.

Se o laço fizesse parte do jogo como um todo aí daria para fazer, mas não tem o `break`. A função de validação não sai enquanto não for digitado algo válido, o laço é propositalmente infinito. Claro, há uma saída, mas aí como é uma função, não é do laço que deseja sair, é da função. O `break` funciona também, porque há um `return` implícito no final de toda função, e se não há nada depois do bloco do laço, é ele que será executado, mas acho mais simples ser explícito na saída.

```
def pedeChute():
    while True:
        try:
            chute = int(input("chute: "))
            if chute == 0:
                return chute
        except:
            pass

def jogo():
    while True:
        #algo aqui
        chute = pedeChute() #sempre será válido
        #algo aqui
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/SUQfER). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qipljvge-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/FunctionValidanting.py).

Se fizer sentido ter a comparação fora da função (não parece mas pode ser), então seria só uma forma de saída do laço do jogo e não uma validação, então poderia fazer assim:

```
def pedeChute():
    while True:
        try:
            chute = int(input("chute: "))
            return chute
        except:
            pass

def jogo():
    while True:
        #algo aqui
        chute = pedeChute() #sempre será válido
        if chute == 0:
            break
        #algo aqui
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/N4KHcv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/avegbqrz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Algorithm/FunctionExit.py).

Note que na função que pede o dado não faz uma validação completa, apenas analisa se foi digitado um número.

Esse é um erro típico de junior mesmo (ou treinee) e pelo menos nesse ponto dá uma indicação que quer chegar a pleno (algumas pessoas não querem, elas passarão teimosas e não perguntarão, farão errado a vida toda, e por isso não evoluirão). Ele não é um erro de código, mas de definição de responsabilidade, um junior erra isso, um pleno já não podem, por isso tem muita gente com esse título mas não capacidade para tanto. Aprendendo isso já ajuda passar para o próximo nível, mas entendendo que quando não sabe se pergunta e escuta quem já tem a experiência é o que mais faz evoluir.

Comment: Cara, obrigado. Sempre fiquei me perguntando se existia uma forma diferente de se fazer, sei que não se deve fazer isso porque não é boa pratica mas sempre ficava na minha cabeça "será que dá pra fazer de outro jeito?".

Answer (score 5):

Não entendi o motivo de não querer fazer o `break` no `while`. Lá é o lugar dele, não faz sentido deixá-lo noutra função.

O que você pode fazer é modelar o código um pouco diferente. Algo como:

```
def fazer_jogada():
  return int(input("chute: "))

def jogo():
  jogada = fazer_jogada()
  while jogada != 0:
    # lógica do jogo
    jogada = fazer_jogada()

jogo()
```

<sup>**[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso449742)**</sup>

Comment: Na verdade não tem muito motivo, mas sempre fiquei pensando se teria uma forma diferente ( talvez até melhor ) daquela que eu conheço.